# Python list and how to sum it up

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following list:

```
['3036', '7209', '4497', '6702', '8454', '7449', '3665', '7936', '9772', '7114', '956', '2564', '8003', '1704', '3816', '6662', '5858', '7777', '6482', '9634', '8805', '7123', '9703', '4676', '6373', '2834', '7221', '2981', '5415', '6872', '4806', '5460', '8533', '3538', '9663', '8001', '9795', '8752', '1117', '5349', '4509', '1004', '9258', '4183', '4034', '3342', '3482', '8567', '1052', '8135', '5561', '517', '1218', '8877', '8062', '1720', '279', '2054', '801', '918', '8687', '7073', '1865', '7084', '2923', '63', '8824', '1079', '5801', '5047', '5', '2572', '5616', '171', '3062', '9552', '7655', '829', '6096', '2312', '6015', '7100', '9548', '2727', '1792', '8402', '42']
```

The `sum()` function gives me Traceback, how to sum those numbers up?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot sum your list because the numbers are represented as a string. What you could do is, 1st transform the list to int, 2nd sum it:

```
>>> int_list = map(int, my_str_list)
```

where `my_str_list` is your original list. `map` applies a function (`int` in this case) to each of the elements of the list as the 2nd parameter, returning a *transformed* list. In this case, your list is transformed to integers.

Then, just sum it:

```
>>> sum(int_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception you're getting is because you're trying to use `sum()` with strings. The documentation states the following:

> `sum(sequence[, start]) -> value`
>
> Return the sum of a sequence of numbers **(NOT strings)** plus the value
>       of parameter 'start' (which defaults to 0).

Given this, if you want to use `sum()` with strings, a pythonic way of doing so would be to use a [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to convert your strings to integers, as follows:

```
>>> l = ['3036', '7209', '4497', '6702', '8454', '7449', '3665', '7936', '9772', '7114', '956', '2564', '8003', '1704', '3816', '6662', '5858', '7777', '6482', '9634', '8805', '7123', '9703', '4676', '6373', '2834', '7221', '2981', '5415', '6872', '4806', '5460', '8533', '3538', '9663', '8001', '9795', '8752', '1117', '5349', '4509', '1004', '9258', '4183', '4034', '3342', '3482', '8567', '1052', '8135', '5561', '517', '1218', '8877', '8062', '1720', '279', '2054', '801', '918', '8687', '7073', '1865', '7084', '2923', '63', '8824', '1079', '5801', '5047', '5', '2572', '5616', '171', '3062', '9552', '7655', '829', '6096', '2312', '6015', '7100', '9548', '2727', '1792', '8402', '42']
>>> sum([int(x) for x in l])
445822
```

You could also omit the brackets (which makes it a generator expression) to avoid duplicating the list in memory:

```
sum(int(x) for x in l)
```

A third option, similar to the first one in the way that it duplicates the list in memory, is to use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to map your list of strings to integers, as follows:

```
sum(map(int, l))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ['3036', '7209',...]
sum = 0
for l in list:
    sum += int(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

use reduce to get the accumulative sum

```
 data=['3036', '7209', '4497', '6702', '8454', '7449', '3665', '7936', '9772', '7114', '956', '2564', '8003', '1704', '3816', '6662', '5858', '7777', '6482', '9634', '8805', '7123', '9703', '4676', '6373', '2834', '7221', '2981', '5415', '6872', '4806', '5460', '8533', '3538', '9663', '8001', '9795', '8752', '1117', '5349', '4509', '1004', '9258', '4183', '4034', '3342', '3482', '8567', '1052', '8135', '5561', '517', '1218', '8877', '8062', '1720', '279', '2054', '801', '918', '8687', '7073', '1865', '7084', '2923', '63', '8824', '1079', '5801', '5047', '5', '2572', '5616', '171', '3062', '9552', '7655', '829', '6096', '2312', '6015', '7100', '9548', '2727', '1792', '8402', '42']

answer=reduce(lambda x,y: int(x)+int(y),data)

print(answer)
```

output

```
445822
```

Answer (score -1):

Elements of your list are of **string type**.

To use sum(list), you must have all the elements of your list to be of numeric(means double) data type (Or integer data type).

**Different ways of doing it are given below.**

1. Using map(int, list) function, for example:

   list = ['1', '3']

   list = map(int, list)

   print sum(list)
2. Using loop, for example:

   list = ['1', '3']

   list = [int(i) for i in list]

   print sum(list)